# I am making a clock but the minutes in my code does not update. How can I fix this?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a python code that tells time as one of my first beginner projects. I was able to finally figure out some of the issues that I had with concatenation all by myself! (woo props to me). However, it seems that the loop that I put my code in, does not update the minutes to the current time but instead, repeats the minutes that it had started with originally. Is my loop wrong? What am I doing wrong here?

```
import time
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()


while True:
    if now.hour > 12:
        print(str(now.hour-12) + ":" + str(now.minute,) + ":" + str(now.second) + " PM")
        time.sleep(1)   
    elif (now.hour >= 12):
        print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second) + " PM")
        time.sleep(1)    
    else:
        print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second) + " AM")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Did you try indenting the if elif and else blocks?

Comment: The code as you've posted it won't run at all. There's no indented block under `while True:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set your time out side of the While loop. Instead, set it inside so it updates on each loop.

```
while True:
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now.hour > 12:
        print(str(now.hour-12) + ":" + str(now.minute,) + ":" + str(now.second) + " PM")       
    elif (now.hour >= 12):
        print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second) + " PM")  
    else:
        print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second) + " AM")
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I see now thanks for this. Such a simple solution, sorry I didn't see this! Thank you! This makes sense!

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

The object does not update itself.
You must call datetime.datetime.now() everytime you want to update the time.
You must call it inside the loop or create a function

here it works

```
import datetime
import time

def now():
   return datetime.datetime.now()

while True:
    if now().hour > 12:
        print(str(now().hour-12) + ":" + str(now().minute,) + ":" + str(now().second) + " PM")
        time.sleep(1)
    
    elif (now().hour >= 12):
        print(str(now().hour) + ":" + str(now().minute) + ":" + str(now().second) + " PM")
        time.sleep(1)
    
    else:
        print(str(now().hour) + ":" + str(now().minute) + ":" + str(now().second) + " AM")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

" now" is defined outside the loop.. you only fetch the system time when loop starts, after that the loop is just formatting the same time. define "now" inside the While loop.

Answer (score 0):

The value for your variable now needs to be updated every time you loop:

```
import time
import datetime

while True:
now = datetime.datetime.now()
if now.hour > 12:
    print(str(now.hour-12) + ":" + str(now.minute,) + ":" + str(now.second) + " PM")
    time.sleep(1)

elif (now.hour >= 12):
    print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second) + " PM")
    time.sleep(1)

else:
    print(str(now.hour) + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second) + " AM")
    time.sleep(1)
```